# extracting string that starts with and ends with something in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Here is the pattern:

```
string str =
   "+++++tom cruise 9:44AM something text here \r\n +++++mark taylor 9:21PM";
```

only string that starts with `+++++` and ends with `AM` or `PM` should get selected. What is Regex.split or linq query pattern?

Comment: Accept an answer or atleast drop a comment to show whether any answer is helpful to u or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
@"[+]{5}[^\n]+[AP]M"

var str = "+++++tom cruise 9:44AM something text here \r\n +++++mark taylor 9:21PM";
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"[+]{5}[^\n]+[AP]M").Captures[0];
match.Value.Dump();
```

Output:

```
+++++tom cruise 9:44AM
```

or:

```
@"[+]{5}\D+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[AP]M
```

I recommend this regex. It will match until at find a hour on format xY:xY:AM/PM where Y is opcional. Test drive:

```
string str = "+++++tom cruise 9:44AM something text here \r\n +++++mark taylor 9:21PM";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"[+]{5}\D+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[AP]M"))
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Output:

```
+++++tom cruise 9:44AM
+++++mark taylor 9:21PM
```

Comment: Your "recommended" version is still greedy, and can match multiple entries at once.

Answer (score 3):

Talon almost got it, but you need a minimal capture, not greedy.  Try

```
[+]{5}.*?(A|P)M
```

Comment: I golfed it down to `\+{5}.*?[AP]M` :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Yeah, that's a tiny bit better yet.  The important thing is working though.

Comment: indeed, so I upvoted your answer instead of posting my tiny improvement :P

Comment: @BenVoigt thats so nice... U downvoted an answer and now when corrected not even ready to take a moment to upvote it.

Comment: @akhil: I didn't downvote your answer.  Anyway, yours still has a problem with being greedy.

Comment: @BenVoigt aleast tell me whether now the answer is correct or not.

Comment: But that was what is required.

Answer (score 2):

The regex would be:

```
[+]{5}.*AM|[+]{5}.*PM
```

You can try it here: http://regexpal.com/

It's first capture was:

```
+++++tom cruise 9:44AM
```

and the second was

```
+++++mark taylor 9:21PM
```

Comment: Isn't `.*` greedy?  Wouldn't that return the whole thing as one big match?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure what C# Regex defaults to but I imagine there is a way to make `.*` not greedy.
But if that's not possible, I believe replacing `.*` with `.+?` would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
bool bResult = false;
String strInput = @"+++++tom cruise 9:44AM something text here \r\n +++++mark taylor 9:21PM";
foreach (string s in strInput.Split(new[]{'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    bResult |= Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[+]+.+[AP]M$");
}
```

or for getting results use:

```
var listResult = new List<string>();
String strInput = @"+++++tom cruise 9:44AM something text here \r\n +++++mark taylor 9:21PM";
foreach (string s in strInput.Split(new[]{'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    listResult.Add(Regex.Match(s, @"^[+]+(?<result>.+)[AP]M$").Groups["result"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the exact regex code that searches for the strings as you required

```
 string str = "+++++tom cruise 9:44AM something text here \r\n +++++mark taylor 9:21PM asdasd";
        var fileNames = from Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\++\++\++\++\++.+(PM|AM)")
                         select m.Value;
        foreach (var s in fileNames)
        {
            Response.Write(s.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It will find any sequence of plus signs, without requiring a string of 5.

Comment: @BenVoigt That does not count it for -1. I have edited the regex. I guess Its better now.

Comment: but what if i don't know how many sequences of +++++ are there in a string , how i will specify inside Regex.Matches(str,@"")

Comment: @"[+]+.+(PM|AM)"
This will search for any number of consecutive "+" in the string

Comment: @user1502952 did that wroked?